# What is the correct way to flow type check querySelector/querySelectorAll elements?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, ecmascript-next

## Background

I am implementing Flow  to typecheck my properties in javascript. Its a retro fit and so I'm starting with a small class.

I am using the es2017 stage-2 property definitions, seen [here](https://github.com/hemanth/es-next#class-property-declarations)

Most of the properties for my class are dom elements retrieved with the querySelector.

## Problem

I am having issues getting the correct type for these elements. For example

```
export default class myClass {
  myElement: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.myElement');

  constructor () {
    if (this.myElement !== null) {
      this.myFunc(this.myElement);
    }
  }

  myFunc (element: HTMLElement) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This fails, saying that `this.myElement` if is null and incompatible with `myFunc (element: HTMLElement)`

## Already Tried

I saw another question about something similar with an iFrame. But the solution is very messy. It involves casting to any and then to your correct element. like

```
var myIframe = ((document.querySelector('iframe'): any): HTMLIFrameElement);
```

I do not want to cast elements like this every time.

## Question

Is there a clean solution for declaring elements as types in Flow?

Comment: Have you tried `myElements: ?Node` ?

Comment: @FelixKling I tried this but ran into an issue down the page where I was told that the element may not be defined when i tried to use it. Even though I wrapped all of the logic in an if statement. Making sure that it will be defined

Comment: It seems to work for me here: https://flow.org/try/#0G4QwTgBAZg9jEF4IBMYGMCuBbApgOwBcA6ARwxzAE8BlHAGxzQJjAAoByZAS2HYEoA3ACghXKBFawYfCAG8hECGhh4AzjAZE6MAOaS4RAA7h8BAHIxkOQUIC+QA

Comment: Not sure it 100% qualified as a duplicate, but my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377663/flowtype-constantly-requiring-null-checks/42378322#42378322 expands on this. If you want `: Node` without `?`, you need to prove to the type checker that it is guaranteed to exist, since Flow has no way to know if the query will succeed.

Comment: @FelixKling when declaring a property in a class it seems I must check if it is null before using it in any other class method. The way around it was to pass it down to each method instead of having class globals (properties). 
Is this a way to enforce better coding?  passing params instead of using class attributes?